# Xamarin Forms SQLite SingleOrDefaultAsync

Tags: forms, sqlite, xamarin, asynchronous

How do I use `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` with my SQLite DB tables? I want to do something like this:

`item = _connection.Table<Item>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ItemRef == 123);`

but I can't work out how to drag in the async extension methods.

Comment: according to the docs, `SingleOrDefaultAsync` is part of Entity Framework

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can achieve what I'm after?

Comment: add EF to your project?